# Adding style tags around specific characters only

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add inline styling to only numbers in paragraph elements. For example:

```
<p>This paragraph has the numbers 1 and 2 in it.</p>
```

So in this instance, I would want to put `<span class="style">1</span>`and `<span class="style">2</span>`. Around the two numbers in that paragraph.

I am trying to write a javascript to accomplish this so I don't have to go back into the document I'm working on and manually add the styling tags around each number, as the document is very long.

So far this is what I wrote, but I'm having difficulty figuring out what to do for the next step on how to incorporate the edits back into the paragraph HTML.

```
let regEx=/[0-9]/g;
let list = [];
let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
 for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
 let html = paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
 list.push(html);
   }
 // all paragraphs into one string.
 let joined = list.join(' ');
 // all the numbers in the paragraphs stored in array
 let numbers = joined.match(regEx);
// define array for styling edits
 let edits = [];
// adding the styling tags to each num
 numbers.forEach(function(num){

 edits.push('<span class="style">' + num + '</span>');

// outputs ["<span class='style'>3</span>", "<span class='style'>7</span>", "<span class='style'>4</span>", "<span class='style'>5</span>"]

 });
 // need to insert edits into paragraph html
```

If anyone can offer any suggestions on how I might be able to accomplish this that would be great, I am still relatively new to working with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  const regEx=/([0-9])/g;
  const newHtml = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.replace(regEx, '<span class="style">$1</span>');

  paragraphs[i].innerHTML = newHtml;
}
```

I updated your regex to put the number in a group, then in the string replace you can reference that group, since there is only one it will be $1. As you can see in the replace we are wrapping that with the appropriate span and then plugging it right back into the innerHTML.

I did notice that your regex is only capturing single digit numbers, if you wanted to capture multi-digit numbers, you could update your reg ex like this: /([0-9]+)/g.

I created a simple jsfiddle to show you how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/andyorahoske/dd6k6ekp/35/

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I was looking for you and you made the code simple to understand. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I broke out the most fundamental part of this into a reusable function that you may find helpful in other contexts.

```
/**
 * Wraps numbers in a string with any provided wrapper.
 * @param  {String} str A string containing numbers to be wrapped.
 * @param  {String} wrapper A string with placeholder %s to define the wrapper. Example - <pre>%s</pre>
 * @return {String} The original string with numbers wrapped using the wrapper param.
 */
function wrapNumbers(str, wrapper) {
    var numbersInStr = str.match(/\d+/g) || [];
    var chunks = [];
    var segmentStart = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < numbersInStr.length; i += 1) {
        var number = numbersInStr[i];
        var indexOfNumber = str.indexOf(number);
        var fWrapper = wrapper.replace('%s', number);
        chunks.push(str.slice(segmentStart, indexOfNumber));
        chunks.push(fWrapper);
        segmentStart = indexOfNumber + number.length;
    }
    if(segmentStart < str.length) {
        chunks.push(str.slice(segmentStart, str.length));
    }
    return chunks.join('');
}
```

To use this in your use case it might look like the following:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var wrapper = '<span class="style">%s</span>';
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i += 1) {
    var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    paragraph.innerHTML = wrapNumbers(paragraph.innerHTML, wrapper);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bryceewatson/pen/vRqeVy?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new code https://jsfiddle.net/fazanaka/au4jufrr/1/

```
var element = document.getElementById('text'),
    text = element.innerText,
    wordsArray = text.split(' '),
    newString;

for(var i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++){
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(wordsArray[i])) && isFinite(wordsArray[i])){
    wordsArray[i] = "<span class='style'>" + wordsArray[i] + "</span>";
  }
}
newString = wordsArray.join(' ');
element.innerHTML = newString;
```

I hope it helps you

**UPD:**
For all paragraphs https://jsfiddle.net/fazanaka/qx2ehym4/